# Подсветка активного пункта подменю

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется меню, формирующееся функциями `PHP`. У основных пунктов есть подпункты, которые разворачиваются при нажатии на основной пункт.

Не получается сделать так, чтобы при переходе на ссылку подпункта в меня подсвечивался активный подпункт.

Пример: основной пункт "Черный чай", подпункты "Классический", "Ароматизированный". При переходе на страницу "Классический", этот подпункт должен подсвечиваться.

Я написала указанный ниже скрипт, но он не работает. Даже в случае, если `location` и `link` одинаковы, `result` дает `null`, и срабатывает ветка `else`.

```
$(function () {
    $('.menu ul li a').each(function () {
        var location = window.location.href;
        console.log(location);
        var link = this.href;
        console.log(link);
        var result = location.match(link);
        console.log(result);
        if(result != null) {
            $(this).closest('ul').show();
        } else {
            $(this).closest('ul').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

**Обновление**

В принципе, все упирается в строку сравнения:

```
var result = location.match(link);
```

Она выдает `null`, хотя если смотреть консоль, то там прописаны две одинаковые строки:

```
http://localhost/index-tea.php?id=aroma_black.inc
http://localhost/index-tea.php?id=aroma_black.inc
```

Результат - `null`.

Comment: Если меню формируется на стороне сервера возможно проще будет там добавить необходимые css классы к пункту который активен.

Comment: классу active  пропиши стиль

Answer (score 1):

Пробуйте css классы на элементах менять.

Вы когда в `match` строку передаете, то она преобразуется в регулярное выражение. Если туда спец символы попали типа "+?*", то не найдет. Попробуйте `match('aroma_black')` или `indexOf`.

Answer (score 0):

Такие вещи не реализуются на js хотя бы потому, что сервер уже знает где вы находитесь и поэтому вы ещё на этапе формирования страницы можете добавить/убрать css класс. Как и указал оратор выше.

Если Вы используете какую-то CMS рекомендую посмотреть как это реализуется в ней. Если это что-то самописное - реализуйте сами и не тревожьте js по пустякам.

Answer (score 0):

Конечно правильно писали, что следует такие вещи реализовывать не на стороне клиента.

Но, если поможет, вот готовый и рабочий пример: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ehqgkL8q/1/)

html:

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Пункт 1</a>
        <li><a href="other.html">Пункт 2</a>
        <li><a href="link.html">Пункт 3</a>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

js:

```
$(function(){
    var url = window.location.pathname,
        urlRegExp = new RegExp(url.replace(/\/$/,''));
        $('.menu ul li a').each(function(){
            if(urlRegExp.test(this.href)){
                $(this).addClass('active');
            }
        });
});
```

css:

```
.active {color:red;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте строковое сравнение. Например можно так выделять меню

```
var uri = window.location.pathname;
$('a[href="' + uri + '"]').addClass('active');
```

А по вашему коду вот правки

```
$(function () {
    $('.menu ul li a').each(function () {
        var location = window.location.href,
            link = $(this).attr('href'),
            result = location.indexOf(link) >= 0;
        console.log(location);
        console.log(link);
        console.log(result);
        if(result) {
            $(this).closest('ul').show();
        } else {
            $(this).closest('ul').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

А вообще такие вещи конечно не нужно реализовывать на `js`.